# How to get a chess board from a final position from read_game?

Tags: python, chess, python-chess

Here we successfully parse a PGN game:

```
import chess, chess.svg, chess.pgn, io
game = chess.pgn.read_game(io.StringIO("1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 *"))
print(game)
```

Unfortunately, `board()` is still the initial position. How to get the final position instead?

```
print(game.board())
# r n b q k b n r
# p p p p p p p p
# . . . . . . . .
# . . . . . . . .
# . . . . . . . .
# . . . . . . . .
# P P P P P P P P
# R N B Q K B N R
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [python-chess documentation](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pgn.html) gives the following example:

> ```
> >>> import chess.pgn
> >>>
> >>> pgn = open("data/pgn/kasparov-deep-blue-1997.pgn")
> >>>
> >>> first_game = chess.pgn.read_game(pgn)
> >>> second_game = chess.pgn.read_game(pgn)
> >>>
> >>> first_game.headers["Event"] 
> 'IBM Man-Machine, New York USA'
> >>>
> >>> # Iterate through all moves and play them on a board.
> >>> board = first_game.board()
> >>> for move in first_game.mainline_moves(): 
> ...     board.push(move) 
> ...
> >>> board 
> Board('4r3/6P1/2p2P1k/1p6/pP2p1R1/P1B5/2P2K2/3r4 b - - 0 45')
> ```

So you you need to read the (main line) moves via [`mainline_moves`](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pgn.html#chess.pgn.GameNode.mainline_moves) and push them to a board (get it from [`game.board()`](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pgn.html#chess.pgn.GameNode.board)), and print that board.

Alternatively, you can move the game to the end of the main line using the [`game.end()`](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pgn.html#chess.pgn.GameNode.end) method. Then you can print the game object:

```
game.end().board()
```

Comment: Thank you, `game.end().board()` solved it!